# US citizen traveling to UK on May 31st staying for one month

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, health, covid-19

Hi everyone I currently live in Miami and I am due to leave for the UK on May 31st and I will arrive on June 1st on AA38 from MIA to LHR. I am a US citizen and I will be seeing my British boyfriend in the UK and staying at his home in Brighton for one month before returning to the US. This flight is one of the only international flights still operating from my area because of COVID-19.

I understand many might think I am crazy to make this journey but I have not seen my boyfriend since March 2019 when when went on a trip together to the UK and Italy. I have a bunch of masks with me and I am in good health and I do not mind following the local laws at all times regarding social distancing and quarantine.

Does anyone know if Immigration will allow me to pass through. I know that US citizens can use the E-Gates now and don't undergo questioning by immigration officers but I have heard from the UK Gov website that the E-Gates have been shut down for non-EEA citizens, and I also heard a story of a woman who was refused because she wanted to take care of her pregnant daughter. I am kind of in a tough spot right now. Should I postpone my trip or just take the flight? If I take the flight what can I do to convince Border Force to allow me I have enough funds and I will promise to adhere to local guidelines and I have a place to stay?
Alejandro

---

Ok after closely looking at the situation and talking with my boyfriend and my family I have agreed to post pone my trip to the UK for the time being. 
Thanks for your answers!
Alejandro

Comment: Although the UK is starting to relax the lockdown, it is currently not permitted to have anyone to stay over at someone’s house. The fine for breaching the lockdown is £100. IMHO, your boyfriend should not be encouraging you to make the trip right now.

Comment: Is your boyfriend's home large enough to allow you to isolate yourself from him? Do you both have the self-discipline to maintain isolation for the first two weeks of your visit? If the answer to either question is "No" you will endanger his health as well as your own. While old age and health problems increase the risk, some young, healthy people have had serious cases.

Comment: Just to add that the infection rate is still high. While official numbers show around 2,000 confirmed cases per day, Government surveillance testing currently puts the true figure at around 11,300 https://covid.joinzoe.com/

Comment: "I am kind of in a tough spot right now." No, you are safe and well at home, but are considering putting yourself in a tough spot by travelling.

Comment: UK is a COVID cesspit in terminal decline.

Answer (score 7):

[**Global Level 4 Health Advisory – Do Not Travel**](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/ea/travel-advisory-alert-global-level-4-health-advisory-issue.html)

> The Department of State advises U.S. citizens to avoid all
> international travel due to the global impact of COVID-19. In
> countries where commercial departure options remain available, U.S.
> citizens who live in the United States should arrange for immediate
> return to the United States, unless they are prepared to remain abroad
> for an indefinite period.
>
> At present the Department of State is making every effort to assist
> U.S. citizens overseas who wish to return to the United States. As the
> Covid-19 situation develops, our ability to provide such assistance
> working with commercial airlines or arranging for evacuation flights
> may become more limited or even unavailable. In recent weeks,
> commercial airlines have significantly reduced flight schedules and
> countries have closed airports and borders with little advance notice.
> If you wish to return to the United States, you should make
> arrangements to do so now and contact the nearest U.S. Embassy or
> Consulate  for assistance as needed. There is no guarantee that the
> Department of State will be able to continue to provide repatriation
> assistance and transportation options to the United States may be
> unavailable in the future. If you choose to remain overseas, you
> should be prepared to remain where you are for the foreseeable future.

If conditions worsen again, new travel restrictions and flight cancellations could be imposed with no notice, leaving you stranded abroad. Do not travel during a global pandemic because you miss your boyfriend.

The UK Government is imposing new restrictions, [including a requirement to self isolate for 14 days upon arrival](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control). Those are currently set to take effect on 8 June though. However, there are [other restrictions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-outbreak-faqs-what-you-can-and-cant-do/coronavirus-outbreak-faqs-what-you-can-and-cant-do) that your plans do not comply with:

> You cannot:
>
> visit friends and family inside their homes
>
> stay overnight away from your own home, except for in a limited set of circumstances, such as for work purposes